# Django - ManyToOne relation to a child class

Tags: django, class, inheritance, models, relation

Is there a way to declare this case so that it works? I hope the code is self-explanatory.

```
class A(Model):
    many_to_one = models.ForeignKey(B)
    (...)

class B(A):
    (...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A(Model):
    many_to_one = models.ForeignKey('B')
    (...)

class B(A):
    (...)
```